# using the right query to perform the proper field targeting

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with data like this:
[image]

The 6s and 2s you see correspond to userIDs in a users table.
My goal is that with a single query I can target the 6s or 2s.
I will try to be specific. Suppose I target user_Ids with 6, with a query like the one you will see below is that I get as a result 2 rows, at which both rows you can find 6:

```
                select  appointments.Bookfrom,appointments.Bookedfor 
                from appointments,users 
                where users.email='email' 
                and (appointments.Bookfrom=users.user_ID
                or appointments.Bookedfor=users.user_ID);
```

WHat I want is to get the 6ths in a single row...meaning getting back only one row in which each column has the 6 in it.
SO far I can achieve that with 2 select statements but I cannot do it with just one.Here is one of these statements that will give me what I want but for one column:

```
                select  appointments.Bookedfor
                from appointments,users 
                where users.email='papageorgiou40@hotmail.com' 
                and users.user_ID=appointments.Bookedfor;
```

The result of the above is this:
[image]

I hope I was clear.

Comment: On second thought,maybe it is only a matter of proper php code to get what I want and spend no more time in finding the correct query for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following does the job, it compares the two fields, and it's better to use JOINS for this:

```
SELECT * FROM appointments INNER JOIN users user_editor ON appointments.bookeditor = user_editor.user_ID INNER JOIN users user_from ON appointments.bookfrom = user_from.user_ID WHERE STRCMP(bookfrom, bookeditor) = 1
```